# Delete all rows from pandas dataframe containing 0 as string and integer

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rows, removeall

I am using `read_csv` to load data from Yahoo Finance leads to rows containing 0 sometimes as string and at other times as integer. Trying to drop / delete these rows per Boolean masking:

```
df[(df != '0') & (df != 0)]
```

leads to errors:

```
TypeError: Could not compare ['0'] with block values
```

(in case the dataframe does not have any row with the string value '0') and

```
TypeError: Could not compare [0] with block values
```

(in case the frame does not have any integer value 0).

Comment: could you accept/upvote my answer if it satisfies your question?  If not, could you comment more on your problem?

Answer (score 0):

With the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'int': [0,0,2,3,0,0,1,2,3],
    'string': ['0','1','2','3','0','0','1','2','0']})

   int string
0    0      0
1    0      1
2    2      2
3    3      3
4    0      0
5    0      0
6    1      1
7    2      2
8    3      0
```

The following code should work:

```
df = df[df.string != '0']
df = df[df.int != 0]
```

This gives the following output:

```
   int string
2    2      2
3    3      3
6    1      1
7    2      2
```